Нужно ли удалять application.yml при добавлении профилей?
Добавил в проект application-dev.yml и application-prod.yml. Нужно ли удалять application.yml?
Или можно в него вынести общие конфиги - в таком случае spring boot сам сначала прочитает application.yml, а потом необходимый профиль?
Для полного понимания моего кейса отмечу, что активный профиль я задаю через JVM: -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--spring.profiles.active=production"

Вы можете поэкспериментировать сами :). Но да, именно так и работает - общий конфиг можно оставить в application.yml, а специфичные конфиги разделить по профилям.

Спринг читает оба конфига. Если проперти объявлены в обоих, то используется значение из специфичного конфига.
